# Easy: Addclass removeClass hasClass issue?

Tags: jquery

I have some buttons in a container div that need to toggle active but only 1 active button at a time.

EDIT:

html is: 
div container of .filter(btn, btn, btn, etc)
there are 3 containers of buttons. 
The third container has a button with an id of: #filter1-none

The code below works to have only 1 button active per group.

Additionally, how would I remove active only from the button with an ID of #filter1-none ONLY if any of the other buttons are active?

```
$('.filter .btn').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: What are you coding for?

Comment: Btw `$( '.filter' ).on( 'click', '.btn', ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do something like this:

```
$('.filter .btn').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
});
```

EDIT:

This doens't allow for "toggle" behavior. So, the `.btn`s will behave like radios, not checkboxes. Let me know if your looking for checkbox-type behavior.

Comment: your right, this is a radio button behavior from bootstrap. i had to do this additional jquery because of some other stuff that was affecting the usual bootstrap radio behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like?

```
$('.filter .btn').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.filter').find('.btn.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: but how do I remove the active class from the other button that has the active class?

Comment: Just a possible enhancement. Maybe you could use `$('.filter .btn .actice').removeClass()` as there could be other elements on the page that have a class called `active` too.

Comment: If you have multiple `.filter`'s, this will remove the active class from all of them. So you need to make it relative to `this`.